# Why does the visible light spectrum appear to be circular

Tags: visible-light, perception

I'm not sure if this is an acceptable place to ask this question, as it may have more to do with the biological workings of human eyes than with the physical properties of light, but I'd rather hear a physical explanation than a biological one (if one exists).

Essentially, we often describe the visible spectrum with a color wheel. In this wheel, Red appears next to Purple (violet), but Red and Violet are at opposite ends of the visible light spectrum. What accounts for this? That is, why do we perceive the Visible Light Spectrum as circular, instead of linear?

Comment: You might find this interesting. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9dqJRyk0YM

Comment: @joshphysics I actually had seen that video (though didn't remember it). Henry's video was entertaining, but I don't think it really gave an insight as to _why_ we roll up all the "left over" light into pink. Furthermore, it didn't even attempt to say why rolling up the electromagnetic spectrum makes any sense. Why should EM radiation with the shortest imaginable wavelength be anything like EM radiation with the longest imaginable wavelength?

Comment: duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40763/

Answer (score 5):

I think saying that the visible light spectrum itself appears circular is a bit misleading.  We simply often choose to represent a wide gamut of colors that humans can perceive in the form of a wheel because such a wheel is an intuitive representation with interesting properties.  In particular, for example, the RGB color wheel can help one get an intuitive feel for how humans perceive color.

Humans are [trichromats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichromacy) which means that we see color by processing information from three different color channels.  Specifically, we have three different types of cone cells, each of which sends a signal to our brain, and those signals are processed by our brain yielding a perceived color.  As a result, perceived human color is a function $f(S,M,L)$ of the response values $S$, $M$, and $L$ of the so-called "$S$hort," "$M$edium," and "$L$ong" cones.  The cones are given these names because the short cone has a peak response at relatively short wavelengths of incoming light (blue), the medium cone has a peak response at medium wavelengths, etc.

What does this have to do with the color wheel?  Well, one way to think of a color wheel is that it's a convenient representation of colors you would see upon combining different amounts of three primary colors additively in much the same way that the human eye generates color perception by combining the outputs of your three cones.

Take the RGB color model for example.  Roughly speaking, if you were to shine about the same amounts of blue and red light onto a white screen, then when the resulting light hit your eye, your cones would respond in such a way that the signal sent to your brain would result in seeing magenta.  If you were to do the same thing with red and green, you would see yellow.  If you look at the [RGB color wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAdditiveColor.svg), you can see that the wheel displays this fact nicely because the color you see when you combine other colors is placed in between the colors you are combining.

Comment: Could you explain how the end of the spectrum appears violet when violet is represented as a mixture of red and blue? Also, is it because of some aliasing in the way our eyes perceive the color?

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu Unfortunately I have forgotten basically everything about this since I wrote this answer I'm sorry to say.  To my own dismay, I don't even recall where I learned about what's written in the answer.

Comment: it's alright. I'll look into it.

Comment: Personally, I thing it has to be some aliasing in the band pas filter of sorts that we have in our eye or due to some property of the wave nature of light