# Why does violet (purple) color contain red component?

Tags: visible-light, vision, perception

We see rainbow color on short-wavelength side as violet or purple:

[image]

And this color is obviously contain R component from RGB.

How can this happen, if only blue pines can percept this color, while red pines are on the opposite side of the band?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does light of high frequency appear violet?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40763/)

Comment: [And there are lots of other related questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=purple+red)

Comment: And something deep in the blue (like a He-Cd laser at 441nm) does not look anything like the 'purple' patches above.

Comment: @JonCuster But does it still looks containing some red component?

Comment: No. Not at all.

Comment: @JonCuster sorry, yes, 441 is looks like should be blue. Purple should be around 400 nm.